# How to iterate through a list and combine the data

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, duplicates

I'm looking to iterate through a list that has the source IP, destination IP, time and packet length. If there are any lines that contain the same source IP and destination IP I need to remove the duplicated lines and show the start time, stop time and the total packet length.

```
def combine_data(source, dest, time, length):
    CombinePacket = []
    CombinePacket = [(source[i], dest[i], time[i], length[i]) for i in range(len(source))]
    counter = 0
    line = []

    for i, j in zip(source, dest):
        if(source[counter] and dest[counter] == source[counter+1] and dest[counter+1]):
            print(CombinePacket[counter-1], CombinePacket[counter])
            counter+=1
    return 0 


(['172.217.2.161'], ['10.247.15.39'], '13:25:31.044180', '0') 

(['172.217.2.161'], ['10.247.15.39'], '13:25:31.044371', '46')
```

I'm expecting to combine the lines and it should look like this:

```
(['172.217.2.161'], ['10.247.15.39'], '13:25:31:044180', '13:25:31:044371', '46')
```

Comment: you have `source[counter] and dest[counter] == source[counter+1] and dest[counter+1]` which means `(source[counter]) and (dest[counter] == source[counter+1]) and (dest[counter+1])`. You have to check `source[counter] == source[counter+1] and dest[counter] == dest[counter+1]`. Eventually use tuples `(source[counter], dest[counter]) == (source[counter+1], dest[counter+1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't add some data to test code and I don't know if this is your problem but you incorrectly compare values in

```
source[counter] and dest[counter] == source[counter+1] and dest[counter+1]
```

beacuse it means

```
(source[counter]) and (dest[counter] == source[counter+1]) and (dest[counter+1])
```

You have to compare every element separatelly

```
source[counter] == source[counter+1] and dest[counter] == dest[counter+1]
```

or you can compare tuples or lists

```
(source[counter], dest[counter]) == (source[counter+1], dest[counter+1])
```

---

Instead of `zip(source, dest):` you can use `zip(CombinePacket, CombinePacket[1:])` and you will have both combined rows which you can use to create new one. And you will get all data as list so you can compare lists with `[source, dest]`

```
results = []

for x, y in zip(combine_packet, combine_packet[1:]):
    if (x[0:2] == y[0:2]):  # `[source, dest]`
        data = [x[0], x[1], x[2], y[2], y[3]]
        print(data)  # (['172.217.2.161'], ['10.247.15.39'], '13:25:31:044180', '13:25:31:044371', '46')
        results.append(data)
```

But I don't know if there can be three rows with the same `source, dest` and what result you expect for these three rows.

---

```
def combine_data(source, dest, time, length):

    combine_packet = list(zip(source, dest, time, length))

    results = []

    for x, y in zip(combine_packet, combine_packet[1:]):
        if (x[0:2] == y[0:2]):
            #print(x)  # (['172.217.2.161'], ['10.247.15.39'], '13:25:31.044180', '0') 
            #print(y)  # (['172.217.2.161'], ['10.247.15.39'], '13:25:31.044371', '46')
            data = [x[0], x[1], x[2], y[2], y[3]]
            print(data)  # (['172.217.2.161'], ['10.247.15.39'], '13:25:31:044180', '13:25:31:044371', '46')
            results.append(data)

    return results


source = [['172.217.2.161'], ['172.217.2.161'], ['0.0.0.0']]
dest   = [['10.247.15.39'], ['10.247.15.39'], ['10.247.15.39']]
time   = ['13:25:31.044180', '13:25:31.044371', '13:25:31.044371']
length = ['0', '46', '123']

combine_data(source, dest, time, length)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I assume this should work if 3 lines match since it would loop through the list checking every element. I should've noted that I'm parsing a tcpdump log file.

Comment: it can combine only two rows - first with second and later second with third. If you want to combine more elements then it may be better to use dictinary with key `(source, dest)` (tuple) and value `[times, lengths]` (list) or `{"times":[...], "lenght":[...]}` (dict)